A user impersonating as an Azure app registration without client secret
I have a C# application that needs to impersonate as an Azure app registration to access some resources.
I have set up federated credential to allow a managed identity to impersonate as the app. Therefore, I can use the code like below on a VM to impersonate as an app registration using managed identity credential:
var clientAssertionCredential = new ClientAssertionCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, new ManagedIdentityClientAssertion(miClientId).GetSignedAssertion);

However, during development, I want to run the code locally.
Although I can create a client secret, store it in a KeyVault, and use it to authenticate as the app, I don't want to use this approach for security concerns.
Is it possible to impersonate as the app using a credential for a user account such as AzureCliCredential or VisualStudioCredential?

What you mentioning here own credentials? whether it is azure credentials(Like username and password?)

@Venkatesan I mean the Azure credential representing an Azure user account (instead of an Azure resource) such as an AzureCliCredential when I login az with my user account.

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request you can use the ROPC flow client identification and user's credentials to the identity provider, and receives tokens in return.


Although I can create a client secret, store it in KeyVault, and use it to authenticate as the app, I don't want to use this approach for security concerns. Is it possible to impersonate as the app using a credential for a user account, such as AzureCliCredential or VisualStudioCredential?

Based on scenario, You can use the ROPC flow to authenticate with a user account and with an app to call an API.
Note:

Microsoft does not recommend this ROPC flow for such scenarios and security.
Accounts with MFA enabled and personal Microsoft accounts are not supported in this method.
You have to use other interactive flows, like the Authorization Code Flow, which directs the user to the browser for login.

Request:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: ClientID
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid
username: User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com
password: UserPassword
grant_type: password
client_secret: Clientsecret

From the above, you will get the token, and using the token, you can call the Microsoft Graph API.
Request:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Authorization: 
Bearer <token>

To avoid passing the client_secret, enable public client flows as shown below.
Portal:

Reference:
Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Learn

Thank you! To my understanding, the ROPC flow allows issuing an access token as a user. However, what I want is an access token representing the app itself. The token will be used for server-to-server calls. It's more like the client credential flow mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials . I wonder if there's also a way to let a user impersonate as an app for development purpose without a long-term secret like client secret or certificate.

If you want to call server-to-server then the only way is client credential flow but this flow required client secret as a mandatory parameter.

Thanks a lot, I'm trying to know the reason for a whole day, until I saw your answer! really helpful!
